# Why nmap closed my connection?

Tags: nmap, nc

I started new connection on port `3333` typing `nc -l 3333`. Then in other terminal window I typed `nmap -sT -O localhost` to check if `3333` port is really open. After this command my connection on port `3333` ends. That is each time. Can you explain me why it happens?

Comment: If the existing answer solved your problem, please consider accepting it with the checkmark; thank you!

Answer (score 4):

Using `nc -l 3333` tells netcat to start listening on port 3333. Once `nmap -sT` (meaning: [scan with TCP Connect](https://nmap.org/book/man-briefoptions.html)) connects, it then *disconnects*, leaving netcat with nothing to do but exit. You may be interested in [nc](http://linux.die.net/man/1/nc)'s `-k` flag, which says:

> Forces nc to stay listening for another connection after its current connection is completed. It is an error to use this option without the -l option.

Comment: If the `-sS` (TCP half-open SYN scan) option is given, the connection will not be completed and the listener will still be able to receive a connection.